# How do I add the <li> tag to a TWIG multivalue text field?

Tags: for-loop, drupal, twig, html-lists, drupal-8

I have a Drupal site with a field that can have multiple values.

How do the `<li> </li>` tags for each value of the field with TWIG ?

```
<ul>
  {{ store.field_professionnel_livraison }}
</ul>
```

The following code displays the field in plain text (but only the first value), I don't know if it can be helpful :

```
{{ store_entity.field_professionnel_livraison.value }}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuadX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiGZ7.png)

How can I use the example below with my previous code :

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html?fbclid=IwAR0OA8K4kp5h4prMU0eNzcJTwzbUyhDkNmQ3GGeIHk0YDfCxaGof8RgyoKw

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208723/iterate-through-multiple-value-content-field-in-twig-template)

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you, I hadn't thought of the field model and it works